# need to convert select queries to with function in sql

Tags: sql

```
select id from u where tKey in (select id from t where tlkey = 1117)
and u.ckey = 15
union all
select * from u where tKey in (select id from t where tlkey = 1116)
and u.ckey = 15
union all 
select * from u where tKey in (select id from t where tlkey = 16)
and u.ckey = 15
union all 
select * from u where tKey in (select id from t where tlkey = 1118)
and u.ckey = 15
union all 
select * from u where tKey in (select id from t where tlkey = 1119)
and u.ckey = 15
```

table u:-

```
id      tKey
16      1047
20      34
35      34
1116    1048
1117    1048
1118    1047
1119    1049
```

table t:-

```
id     tlkey 
34      16
1047    1116
1048    1117
1049    1118
```

expected output:-

```
id
1116
1117
16
1118
20
35
1119
```

hello

i want to this convert query in to sql with function i can't understand how can i do that. first query output is  (1117, 1116)
second query output  is (16 , 1118) means we need to used first query output to second then go last level i dont know what is last 
how can i do that please help me

Comment: How come you "want to this convert query in to sql with function"? Explain!

Comment: because it is recursive queries means. first query output input for other query. than output of that query input for other query

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Comment: @jarlh please check that

Comment: With that sample data you simply want `select id from u`... Add some rows to each table - not expected to be returned.

Comment: It looks like you're following relationships.
With 1117 as input, you get 1048 (from table t) and from that get 1116 and 1117 from table u. Then you do it again for 1116. In the end, the relationships followed are: 1117 -> 1048 -> (1116, 1117); 1116 -> 1047 -> (1118, 16); 16 -> 34 -> (20, 35); 1118 -> 1049 -> (1119);
So I see the recursion. But that's not a very SQL way of doing things.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to select from a table 'u' with the id in a range of values.

Have you tried the IN operator in the inner query?
Like this:

```
SELECT * FROM u
WHERE tKey IN (
    SELECT id 
    FROM t 
    WHERE tlkey IN (1117, 1116, 16, 1118, 1119)
)
AND u.ckey = 15
```

Comment: i have only one id that is 1117 remaining all ids are output so how can i find to the other ids

Comment: Then I don't understand what you need. Do you have an existing query you're supposed to copy?